# When converting first page of a PDF into an image using Ghostscript, sometimes I get "extra" space. Why?

Tags: pdf, command-line, png, ghostscript

I am building a simple script which converts the first page of a PDF into an image using Ghostscript. Here is the command I use:

```
gs -q -o output.png -sDEVICE=pngalpha -dLastPage=1 input.pdf
```

This works beautifully with some PDFs, e.g. if I convert the first page of a PDF that looks like this:

[image]

I actually get this first page as an image and there aren't any problems.

But I have noticed that with some first pages of other PDFs, like the following:

[image]

With the same `gs` command, after the conversion, the .png image looks like this:

[image]

The problem is that I get this extra white space on the left inside the image when I convert that page, why does GhostsScript do this? Where does that extra blank white space come from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely, your PDFs do not use identical values for `/MediaBox` and for `/CropBox`. For details about these technical terms related to a page, see [this illustration from the German Wikipedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:PDF_BOX_01.svg):

[image]

In other words: the `/CropBox` values (if given) for a PDF page determines which (smaller) part of the overall page information (which is inside the `/MediaBox`) the PDF viewer should be made visible to the user (or to the printer).

### Solution

To determine what are the different values for all the pages of your book(s), run this command:

```
pdfinfo -f 1 -l 1000 -box my.pdf
```

To see these values just for the first page, run

```
pdfinfo -l 1 -box my.pdf
```

For Ghostscript to give the results you want, add `-dUseCropBox` to your command line:

```
gs -q -o output.png -sDEVICE=pngalpha -dLastPage=1 -dUseCropBox input.pdf
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for explanation! The gs option worked like a charm! As I am using OS X and `pdfinfo` is not available, can I determine the different values for */MediaBox* and */CropBox* using `pdftk`? How? Please correct me if I am wrong, what I understood from your explanation was: Every PDF page has a *metaset* of information which describes what should be made visible. The **/MediaBox** is the part of the page which contains the global information of a page. Inside the MediaBox, a PDF page has different parts and only the **/CropBox** infos determine which part of the page to show, right?

Comment: @user3019105: On OSX you can install pdfinfo via **[MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/install.php)**. Once you have the MacPorts base installation, just run (in a terminal): `sudo port -pf install poppler poppler-data`. (As an alternative to MacPorts, you could also use `brew` -- but I have no personal experience with this.) Where did you get your Ghostscript for OSX from???

Comment: @user3019105: Your understanding of the `/MediaBox` and `/CropBox` is basically correct. `/MediaBox` is a value that ***must*** be present for a PDF document. `/CropBox` is optional and may be defined globally (once for all pages) or page-wise. If not give, the viewer assumes the same values for `/CropBox` as are defined for `/MediaBox`.

Comment: I have installed gs from MacPorts as its path is `/opt/local/bin/gs`. As for `pdfinfo` I tried to search for it (`port search --line --name --glob '*pdfinfo*'`) and found nothing (also tried with HomeBrew), but I didn't know it comes with `poppler poppler-data` ports. Thank you for your precise and concise explanation!